# Есть ли в typescript флаги оптимизации?

Tags: typescript

Например, как в gcc, g++: -O2, -O3 и т.д.

Допустим такое:

```js
let a = 1 * 2 * 3;
```

После компиляции должно стать таким:

```js
let a = 6;
```

Comment: таких флагов нет, но, возможно, можно написать или взять существующий плагин для комилятора

Comment: Как правильно упомянул Grundy, таких флагов нет, но при этом можно написать подобные выражения в `enum`, допустим: `enum MyEnum { a = 1 * 2 * 3 }; console.log(MyEnum.a) // 6` (на выхлопе будет сам результат выражения, а не оно само)

Comment: Эти оптимизации выполняет JavaScript JIT. На уровне typescript их нет - не нужны.

Comment: tsc придерживается цели не изменять исходный js и работать только с типами https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals